# App crashes when deleting an LWM2M object using mbed-client on mbed-os

Tags: arm, mbed, coap

How do can I delete an object and its instance while mbed client is connected to the device server?

Currently I have a class that creates an object in the constructor and I register it with mbed client. I would also like to delete this object when the destructor is called. I'm trying the following:

In the constructor:

```
object = M2MInterfaceFactory::create_object(name);
instance = object->create_object_instance();
```

In the destructor:

```
object->remove_object_instance(instance->instance_id());
// delete object;
```

The above code works but the object is never removed from memory.

If I uncomment the line to call the object's destructor then my application crashes. I used mbed-trace to see if there are any error messages, but couldn't find anything. [Here](https://jpst.it/VCXz) is the output of the log from the call to the destructor until the app crashes.

I'm using a Nucleo-F401RE with mbed-os 5.4.1.

Comment: Did you unregister first (with mbed Client) before removing the resource?

Comment: No, the client is still registered. My intention is to create and delete objects dynamically while the client is still connected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not allowed according to the OMA LwM2M spec.

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation, you have to de-register first and then delete the interface/resources.

However, I have seen that mbed client interface for some reason cannot be created more than 6 times after successive destruction; one the 7th occasion client cannot connect to server and returns 'M2MIvaildParametersError'. I will be grateful if someone can comment on this?